# How to change border/background color for android gallery

Tags: android, gallery, setbackground

I created a simple gallery following a tutorial.
Everything works fine but i wasn´t able change the border/background color.
Maybe a small image helps to understand my Problem.
[desired colorchanges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuxvF.png)

I get a scaled image with a dark grey filled background. These rectangle is bordered in a light gray which I want to change.

I tried:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);      
  imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmaps[position]);
  imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(300, 200));
  imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
  imageView.setBackgroundResource(imageBackground);         
  **imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);**
  ...
```

but this doesn´t work because the dark grey part is painted in blue, too.
Any ideas?

Edit: adding some code snippets and wrong result

Using *setBackgroundColor* will lead to this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMch1.png)

My gallery creation:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   

  mGallery = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.imgGallery);    
  mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
  mGallery.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

But when

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

is called
*convertView* is null.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (I haven't tested though):

```
switch (position) {
            case 1:
                imageView.setBackgroundColor(convertView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            //... and so on
        }
```

You could alse try this one `imageView.setBackgroundColor(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));`

Let me know if this didn't help you!

**EDIT:**

Try with this and let me know if anything changes:

`imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));`

Another option is, instead of instantiating that `ImageView` programatically, just build your own xml with your `ImageView` inside and later do an `LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.your_image_view, parent, false);`

Comment: doesn´t seem to work. I put some more details in the question post. Maybe this helps...